# JSON format for a Vector of numbers

Tags: java, json, vector

I'd like to populate a Java double vector, `double dNumber[]`, from a JSON String. In Java I just have one variable `dNumber`.

Is there any way I can use one variable in JSON with the list of values. I don't want to create a separate JSON name for each item in the array.

Thanks.

Al

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
A JSON can contain an array of values. The syntax is

```
{
  dNumbers: [ 12.5, 6.8, 3.1415],
  [...]
}
```

More on JSON [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp)